# How To Get WordPress Categories Last Update Date?

Tags: functions, categories, post-meta

I am trying to make a custom sitemap for my WordPress blogs categories. For that I added the below code in my `functions.php` file and save it. Now all things is working fine but I want to get the date of category when it was last updated and want to put it instead of fix date at `2015-02-02` so that it will show every category posts last updated date there in this format.

Note: Last updated mean when I last time publish a post in this category.

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *  Custom Dynamic XML Sitemap Generator For Categories
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
add_action("publish_post", "cat_create_sitemap");
add_action("publish_page", "cat_create_sitemap");
function cat_create_sitemap() {
  $categoriesForSitemap = get_categories(array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, 
    'depth' => 0, 
    'hierarchical' => false
  ));

  $sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  $sitemap .= '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sitemap-style.xsl"?>';
  $sitemap .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

  foreach($categoriesForSitemap as $category) {
    $sitemap .= '<url>'.
      '<loc>'. get_category_link($category->term_id) .'</loc>'.
      '<priority>1</priority>'.
      '<lastmod>2015-02-02</lastmod>'.
      '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>'.
    '</url>';
  }
  $sitemap .= '</urlset>';
  $fp = fopen(ABSPATH . "custom-cat-sitemap.xml", 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $sitemap);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: The update/creation date isn't stored for categories, like for posts/pages.

Comment: @birgire So you mean that there is no solution for my desire?

Comment: One workaround would be to hook into the category's update & creation process and save the data to the wp_options table. But I wonder if you mean another kind of update date: when a post was last updated in a given category?

Comment: I mean the second one as to **Get a date of category when the last posts was updated/published in that category.** So is this possible?

Comment: You can always use `get_posts()` with relevant input arguments. For example `posts_per_page` as `1` and `orderby` as `modifed`, ... etc